# What does it mean when a kernel terminates a process with status 131?

Tags: linux, kernel, syslog

I am trying to debug an issue where a redis-server process died, and in the syslog I see:

```
Mar  9 23:56:44 ip-10-236-158-228 kernel: [25188369.962457] init: redis1-server main process (2822) terminated with status 131
```

What does status 131 mean, and where can I get a list of termination status codes? I googled for `linux kernel terminated with status` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does status 131 mean, and where can I get a list of termination
>   status codes?

According to [this list of items](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/linux-error-codes/), status 131 equates to `ENOTRECOVERABLE` which means, “State not recoverable.” What that means in the context of your Redis server instance failing is hard to clearly understand without knowing more specific details about your Redis server setup.

Comment: Thank you for this link. I think it's likely because my redis-sever instance ran out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

The exit codes or statuses of *nix programs are program-specific. You’ll find the answer you need in the documentation of the program in question. Usually, this is in a man page (type `man <name of program>`). In this particular case, you should look in the documentation accompanying redis1-server.

Also, that’s not the kernel terminating anything; that’s the kernel saying that init is saying that `redis1-server` terminated.